# In what situation are mutexes necessary?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, race-condition

Can someone help me out with example of a situation in which absence of mutexes "definitely" leads to an incorrect result.

I need this so that I could test my mutex implementation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider any correct code that uses mutexes for synchronization. By removing the locking, you will introduce new (possibly incorrect) behaviors (executions) to the program. However, the new code will still contain all of the old behaviors, therefore there will always be at least one execution that will yield a correct result. Hence, what you're asking for is impossible.

Comment: i think that only holds, if you don't stop a particular process to affect the order in which instruction are executed.

Comment: wouldn't it be nice if such a test existed, which was **guaranteed** to uncover synchronization bugs. Unfortunately, as @avakar says, it's impossible. Removing synchronization only expands the range of possible behaviors. It doesn't prevent the correct behavior from occuring.

Answer (score 2):

Make a program that has a fork() in it. Then, make both the child process and the parent process read a number from the same file, increment it and then write it back to the file. Do this 100 times in each process.

Comment: This will probably, but not *definitely* cause synchronization problems.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need a mutex (or similar mechanism) when there is a need from mutual exclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Are you just testing that it locks correctly? If so maybe something like this? Two threads

```
#Global Variables
int counter = 1
int factorial = 1


#Critical Section
counter++
Delay for some amount of time
factorial *= counter
#End Critical Section
```

If your Mutex works then the end result should be 6. Otherwise it will be 9. **Edit** or 3 I suppose as the `*=` is not atomic but not 6 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The classic case is the ATM shared by husband and wife.  One makes a deposit, the other a withdrawal in different threads.  If the critical section isn't guarded appropriately by a mutex it's possible for each of them to see inconsistent results.

If a "definite situation" is required, have the husband make a deposit and then sleep for sufficient time so the wife can make a withdrawal.  The husband's result will overwrite the wife's, and the the account balance isn't ACID anymore.

Comment: If you understand my question correctly, i dont need a "possiblity", i need a "definite situation" which is guarranted to produce wrong results.

Answer (score 0):

I think not, because the scheduler as implemented in current OSes is not deterministic from an application's point of view. However, if you start a lot of threads and test the code several times, the probability of a clash should be high enough.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the kind of test I used in my mutex implementation test suite:

```
// global:
enum { HUGE_VAL = 50000 }
Mutex mutex;
int variable;

// main thread
mutex.lock();
thread.run();
for(int i = 0; i < HUGE_VAL; ++i)
    ++variable;
assert(variable == HUGE_VAL);
mutex.unlock();
thread.join();
assert(variable == -HUGE_VAL);

// parallel thread
mutex.lock();
variable = -HUGE_VAL;
mutex.unlock();
```

Of course, adapt HUGE_VAL as you feel it, because a mutex is used to protect from concurrent acces. Therefore, to test it, you need to create concurrency, and the faster the machine, the huger HUGE_VAL should be...

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate the famous ["bank transfer" scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974596/what-is-transaction/974611#974611) used to illustrate database transactions. We have accounts A and B and need to transfer 200 bucks from A to B.

C++ - like pseudocode (not tested)

```
 int accountA = 200;
 int accountB = 0;

 void transfer( int& from, int& to, int amount )
 {
     //mutex acquisition should be here
     if( from < amount ) {
         printf( "error" );
         // mutex release should be here
         return;
     }
     from -= amount;
     Sleep( 5000 ); //wait idle for 5 seconds
     to += amount;
     // mutex release should be here
 }

 void display( const int& account1, const int& account2 )
 {
     //mutex acquisition should be here
     Sleep( 3000 ); //wait 3 seconds
     printf( "%d", account1 );
     printf( %d", account2 );
     // mutex release should be here
 }
```

now spawn two threads and execute `transfer( accountA, accountB, 200 );` on one and `display( accountA, accountB );` on another starting at the same moment of time.

On a system without load the program will show that money have disappeared "in the middle of transfer" - the accounts are read in the middle of "transaction" (the problem there's no transaction here), so there's no isolation. With mutexes you would see the final state - "after the transfer".