# How does JPA2.0 handle concurrent requests by client?

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee

How does JPA handle single request and 1000 requests for the same data from database?

Is there any change in accessing the speed of data if 1000 request same data at a time?

How it handles single request and multiple requests if all request access the same data from database?

Answer (score 1):

Within in a typical transaction manager configuration you have an own transaction created for each request. 
The concurrency is then being handled by your database.

For more information about transaction handling take a look at the posts of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974596/what-is-a-transaction).