# How to make operation atomic while inserting in mysql using perl script

Tags: mysql, perl

I have a perl script that places order for customer.

2 tables.

```
table_orders - orderic, customerid, orderdatetime
table_order_details - orderid, productname, Quantity, MRP. Sellprice
```

Steps to insert into table:

```
1. insert in table_orders.
2. for each product in shopping cart insert into table_order_details
```

Now problem is after insert in first table,

```
1. It is possible because of some error in input data insertion in second table is not possible and perl returns an error.
2. Few entries done in table 2 too, but now got the error so further entry not possible in table 2 and perl returns an error.
```

In both the cases transaction is not completed successfully, so how to revert back the entries in DB that was done before error occurred?

Is there any perl or MYSQl wat to do this or we need to handle it manually??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974596/what-is-a-database-transaction).

Transactions allow you to isolate changes to the database until you're done making all the changes. Nobody else can see those changes and nobody else can change those rows while you're working in your transaction. Then you `commit` the transaction and everyone else can see your changes all at once. If there's an error, you can `rollback` all the changes you made in your transaction.

In Perl, using DBI, the default is to not use transactions. Every statement is automatically committed. It is a *very* good idea to *always* turn transactions on.  You typically do this when connecting to the database by setting [AutoCommit](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#AutoCommit) off. You'll also want to turn on [RaiseError](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#RaiseError) so database errors will happen automatically, you don't have to write `or die...` everywhere. Then, since you don't want to see errors twice, turn [PrintError](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#PrintError) off.

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect(
    'dbi:mysql:...', $user, $pass,
    { AutoCommit => 0, RaiseError => 1, PrintError => 0 }
);
```

Now everything you do will be in a transaction and nothing you do will be visible to anyone else until you run `$dbh->commit`.  Wrap all the work in an `eval` block to catch any errors thrown now that `RaiseError` is on.  If you get an error, `$dbh->rollback` will throw out any partial work.

```
eval {
    my $insert_table_orders_sth = $dbh->prepare(
        "INSERT INTO table_orders (...) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
    );
    $insert_table_orders_sth->execute(@table_orders_values);

    my $insert_table_orders_details_sth = $dbh->prepare(
        "INSERT INTO table_orders_details (...) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
    );
    for my $product ($cart->products) {
        $insert_table_orders_details_sth->execute($product->values);
    }

    # All done, make the changes visible to everyone else.
    $dbh->commit;
};
if($@) {
    warn "There was a database error: $@";

    # Wipe out anything you did above.
    eval { $dbh->rollback };

    # Do whatever else you might need to cleanup the error.
}
```

Comment: Tip: If you use `RaiseError => 1`, you probably want `PrintError => 0` too to avoid seeing every message twice.

Comment: Since the OP used the MySQL tag: MyISAM, MySQL's default storage engine prior to v5.5, doesn't support transactions; even with AutoCommit disabled, every statement is committed automatically. I think MySQL 5.1 comes with EL6, so this could be a problem for people on older systems. Unfortunately, there would be no indication that transactions aren't being used.

Comment: (It would also be a problem for anyone who chooses to use MyISAM, regardless of MySQL version.)